# How to get keydown event target in contenteditable iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe

When I get keydown event target in contenteditable in iframe, it's always body. How to get actually target in this case?

I try to bind keydown event after iframe loaded or just code in console to bind event by hand, all fail.

```
$('#ueditor_0').contents().keydown(e => console.log(e.target));

$(document.getElementById('ueditor_0').contentDocument).keydown(e => console.log(e.target));
```

None of them works.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)?

Comment: ?? Did you read the linked article?

Comment: I use `about:blank and javascript: URLs `, inherited domain